# Yet Another What am I? Puzzle

Tags: riddle, meta-knowledge

1) From my birth I want to rise

But I shall fall, its no surprise

I should display approval from afar

But pedantic snobs is what you are.

2) I could produce a rise in rank

But not if my cachet has sank

Uplift me please, by 288*

And my master will reach another state

What am I?

*time sensitive

Comment: =.=


That's *evil*. But clever. Upvoted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> Stack Exchange Reputation.

1) From my birth I want to rise

But I shall fall, its no surprise

> Everybody wants their reputation score to improve, but downvotes, vote reversals, and other rep-decreasing events are inevitable.

I should display approval from afar

But pedantic snobs is what you are.

> Rep only goes up if someone else expresses approval of your actions (upvoting a post, approving a suggested edit, etc.), but they won't do that if they're too nitpicky.

2) I could produce a rise in rank

But not if my cachet has sank

> Higher reputations gives more site privileges

Uplift me please, by 288*

And my master will reach another state

> The OP needs approximately 288 rep points (284, when I posted this answer) to break the 2k barrier and achieve new privileges.

What am I?

*time sensitive

Comment: Am I a bad person for reading your answer, and immediately considering a downvote on the question?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are

> Bread

From my birth I want to rise

> Bread rises due to the yeast in it

But I shall fall, its no surprise

> It gets eaten

I should display approval from afar

> Rises in the oven?

But pedantic snobs is what you are.

> People watching it rise in the oven, or criticizing what it tastes like etc?

2) I could produce a rise in rank

> From dough to bread

But not if my cachet has sank

Uplift me please, by 288*

> Cook at 288 degrees, obviously time sensitive

And my master will reach another state

> Bread!

I've left the clues I couldn't get blank

Comment: that's not it, but clever